# Is anyway to make a page preview dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

I have a [Site](https://dailycodes.dev/) that have(/will have) all my things on internet.
I'm doing the [Works](https://dailycodes.dev/works) page that will contain all my projects (they already are on the site but not yet indexed, such as [Aquarium](https://dailycodes.dev/aquarium))

My questions is:
Anyway to make a page preview for my Projects without having to take screenshot of the every page? (I already look into google and found nothing)

What i want to do is like this(done in figma):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ijk.png)

*edit 1: iframe is to hard to control, i wanna to transform this in a link and iframe simple dont work with it

Comment: Have you tried using an `iframe`?

Comment: Doesn't work like i wanted (see edit1)

Comment: *i wanna to transform this in a link and iframe simple dont work with it* - I don't understand this part

Comment: i wanna use <iframe> as a clickable link for other,
 page but for security reasons this isn't possible
(everything that try put above the <iframe> don't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com/">
  <iframe src="https://example.com/"></iframe>
</a>
```

Comment: Strange...
but tks anyway